# Picture of Lambert's proof that $\pi$ is irrational?

Tags: nt.number-theory, continued-fractions, transcendental-number-theory, irrational-numbers, alternative-proof

With a suitably generous notion of "picture proof" or "proof without words" or "geometric proof," there do exist such proofs of [the irrationality of square roots](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/proofs/GraphicalSqRoots.shtml) and even of the [irrationality of $e$](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0704.1282.pdf).  However, I am not aware of anything that could plausibly be called a [geometric proof of the irrationality of $\pi$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1658174).  Given that the original definition of $\pi$ was geometric, it seems a pity that there is no such thing.  Or maybe there is?

Perhaps one can try to draw pictures to accompany [Lambert's irrationality proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/895728). For example, is there a way to draw a picture of the following fact?
$$\tan(a/b) = {a \over\displaystyle b - {a^2 \over \displaystyle 3b - {a^2 \over \displaystyle 5b - {\displaystyle a^2 \over 7b - \cdots}}}}$$
And if so, is there any way to draw a picture of the fact that such a continued fraction is irrational when $a$ and $b$ are positive integers?

Comment: I'll think more about this later but: Let $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ act on $\mathbb{R}$ by Mobius transformations in the usual way. It looks to me like your continued fraction says that $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & x \\ \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 3x \\ \end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 5x \\ \end{bmatrix}  \cdots (0) = \tan(x)$. So maybe draw a sequence of lines given by partial products of this, and see that their slopes are approaching $\tan(x)$ or, equivalently, their angles are approaching $x$? (Here $x = a/b$.)

Comment: Correction: The above formula should have $\tan(x^{-1})$ on the right hand side. I also think there might be a sign error somewhere.

Comment: I don't have a specific suggestion, but of possible related interest is a collection of references I assembled 3 years ago in my answer to [Irrationality of $\pi^2$ and $\pi^3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2584927/13130).